# Nigeria Female headtie ( called Gele in Nigeria)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting

I'm trying to model a female headtie popular used in Nigerian wedding as shown in the images below , i dont realy know exactly how to go about it, im a bit confused either to use clothes feature in blender , or some sort of array modifier  and bend modifiers . Any help will be appreciated 
some the links below will give you an idea
https://www.wikihow.com/Tie-a-Gele
https://www.concise.ng/2019/03/07/how-to-tie-gele/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't feel qualified to answer this - hence the comment only - but I would model the basic form using ordinary mesh, then get the cloth detail there with the texture - especially in the bump channel.  Maybe the beads could be a particle system or an array.

Comment: i will see what i can do , thanks for taking your time to comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could begin with an extruded circle, then some bevels, some additional extrusions if necessary, and deform it a bit with the *Proportional Editing* option on. Then give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

For the other side, duplicate and mirror your object. For the node, create a profile shape and a curve, use an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier to make the profile follow the curve, then apply the modifiers and again, rework a bit with the *Proportional Editing* so that it looks a bit more natural (needs to be improved of course). Give it a fabric texture:

[image]

Comment: wow that is impressive and perfect, i wished you did a video recording of this and share a youtube link with us but i still appreciate your answer , i will gradually follow it. Thanks

Comment: still struggling with the extrusion in the image 2 and 3 , mine simply extruded the loop cuts straight up without the bent faces shown in yours

Comment: actually what I've done is moving up several edge loops then beveling with ctrl B, but you could as well select faces and extrude up...

Comment: ok , i got it , thanks and sorry for for asking too much