# How to model this complex knot?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, objects, 3d-view

Have been struggling to model this knot. I've tried using paths but I always somehow mess it up. Is there a way to perhaps box model this? I've been really stuck on this, It is called a Sageo and is a knot found on katana scabbards. If anyone knows a tutorial for this or something else, that would be great!

[image]

Comment: unless you want to do it as a challenge, you could simply fake it?

Comment: How could I fake it?

Comment: you don't have to make a continuous ribbon, just planes intertwining

Comment: Do you happen to know a tutorial or something on it? I am a visual learner, haven't really done something like this. @moonboots

Comment: for example here at the end of my answer, I just faked the knot: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175570/nigeria-female-headtie-called-gele-in-nigeria/175680#175680

Comment: Related: [Modelling a full Windsor knot on a necktie)(https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183459/78972)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a single object to make the whole ribbon you could use several in order to fake it, like that (material is not good):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked out pretty good!