# How to make Curves and Knot?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm facing a really hard time trying to make this knot
[image]

For you guys, what's the best approach to make this knot?
Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: Hello, have you tried a mesh with Array + Curve? The hard part is to correctly place the curve, then you'll need to tilt some vertices. The other solution would be to fake the knot but maybe it's not what you want: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192049/how-to-model-this-complex-knot

Comment: It's driving me nuts trying to work out how this knot is tied in RL.. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Hello!!, It is a Nakayui knot, it belongs to a shinai sword.

Answer (score 2):

Make a curve for the strip any way you like. I use Bezier. So Shift + A -> Curve -> Bezier. Make another curve Circle for the profile of the strip. Now you can select the first curve and in the Properties editor, in curve properties tab, geometry section, select object bevel mode and choose the second curve as profile. You need to edit the profile curve to match the shape of the profile of the strip obviously. Then, you can just extrude curve vertices with E and place them and their handles with move, rotate and scale(G, R, S) and also you can control the tilt of the curve with Ctrl+T. You need to tie the knot this way. It will take some time to do it, and it seems like a hard task, but while it might not be a very pleasant task it's quite clear what you need to do and it does not take a lot of time. That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this right now. 
Once again thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could begin with a simple vertex that you extrude on the top of your object with the *Snap* to face enabled in order to make it stick to the surface. Give it the shape of the knot:

[image]

Then right click and *Convert to > Curve*, go in *Edit* mode and *Curve > Set Spline Type > Bezier*. Create a flat cube, array and make it follow the curve you've created with a *Curve* modifier. Tilt the vertices of you curve so that the shape is correctly oriented all along (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or *Tilt* value in the *N* panel):

[image]

Comment: I will mix your solution with Žiemys' solution, I can’t thank you enough!

Comment: you're welcome, not easy to do  ;)